# Initiating a push segue results in `Pushing a navigation controller is not supported `

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UITableView`, when a user taps on a cell I initiate a segue like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MCExpandedSegue" sender:self];   
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MCExpandedSegue"]){
        // Opens item in browser
        MCExpandedViewController *controller = (MCExpandedViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

In order for the destination view controller (`MCExpandedViewController`) to have a navigation bar and a back button, I've embedded it in a Navigation Controller like so:

[image]

However, upon tapping a cell in the table in order to make this segue, I get the following error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`. Is this because it tries to segue to MCExpandedViewController but gets tripped up because it's contained within the navigation controller? How can I do this segue correctly?

Comment: Is the `MatchCenterViewController` already inside a `UINavigationController`? If that's the case, can you please try to remove the middle `UINavigationController` and add the segue directly to `ExpandedViewController`? You can control the appearance of the navigation controller by accessing `self.navigationController` inside any view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `the navigation controller` and segue
   `MCExpandedViewController` directly.
2. Add this to viewWillAppear: in `MCExpandedViewController.m`

   ```
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
   ```

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your first view controller is embed in navigation controller.
MatchCenterViewController is in navigation controller.
No need of another navigation controller in different scene.